# Why did Paul von Hindenburg wrongly call Adolf Hitler "Bohemian corporal"?

Tags: germany, hitler, austria, terminology, interwar

Paul von Hindenburg didn't like Adolf Hitler because he was a low-ranked individual from the poor/low class. He called him mockingly "Bohemian corporal".

However in reality Adolf Hitler was not Bohemian, but Upper-Austrian, also if I'm not mistaken he was not corporal, but just a soldier which never promoted.

Why didn't he call him correctly "Upper-Austrian soldier" ?

Comment: Silly question -- given Hitler's attempt to be an artist could "Bohemian" have been meant in that sense, rather than ethnic/locality of origin?

Comment: @RobCrawford probably not, the German word for the location is pronounced very differently than the French Boheme. The similarity exists only in English.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Paul von Hindenburg called Hitler a "böhmischer Gefreiter".

He (and others) wrongly assumed that Hitler was born in [Broumov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broumov) (called **Braunau** in German) that is indeed in Bohemia (today Czech Republic). However, that was a mistake, as Hitler was born in the actual town of [Braunau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braunau_am_Inn) in Austria.

At the time of Hitler's birth, both towns belonged to the Austro-Hungarian Empire and were called Braunau by Germans, so it was easy to get wrong.

"Gefreiter" is an enlisted rank in the military. Which was true, [Hitler was Lance corporal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_career_of_Adolf_Hitler) in World War 1.

Answer (score 3):

During the German War in 1866 Paul von Hindenburg served as a 19-year old officier in the Prussian Army. During that war against the Austrian Empire he came across a Bohemian village also named "Braunau". Thats why he mistook Bohemia as Hitler´s birthplace.

Comment: Reference(s) for this fact?